# Distinguish between mouse doubleclick and mouse click in wpf

Tags: wpf, mouseevent, double-click

In my WPF application , I am using ListView GridView, and I implemented a functionality that is associated to mouse double click.
Is there a way, or a control that distinguish between the mouse double click and mouse click?

I used a button, and implemented an event for mousedoubleclick, but the click event is still triggering

Thanks for help

Comment: you can't have a double-click without a (single) click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you just add the `MouseDoubleClick=` attribute. Check these links out:

- [WPF Tutorial - Getting the DoubleClick Event](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-getting-the-doubleclick-event)
- [MouseDoubleClick MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.control.mousedoubleclick.aspx)
- [Detect mouse double click in WPF - Channel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/255539-Detect-mouse-double-click-in-WPF/)

Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: `MouseDoubleClick` is not a valid event for the `Canvas` control, which what I was having issues with.  It does appear to be valid for other controls.  The answer below from @mcwyrm was what I needed.

Answer (score 39):

Handling the double click event for controls that present the `MouseDoubleClick` event is no trick. Handling double click for other controls involves inspecting the `ClickCount` property of the `MouseButtonEventArgs`.

So, for instance, your XAML might look something like this:

```xml
<SomeControl MouseDown="MyMouseDownHandler">
    ...
</SomeControl>
```

... and your code behind like this:

```cs
private void MyMouseDownHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount == 2)
    {
        // Handle double-click
    }
}
```

[Here's](https://web.archive.org/web/20130408052049/http://tech.pro/tutorial/838/wpf-tutorial-getting-the-doubleclick-event) a page that provides a somewhat more detailed example.

Comment: The link is broken, but can be found on Wayback Machine:  https://web.archive.org/web/20130408052049/http://tech.pro/tutorial/838/wpf-tutorial-getting-the-doubleclick-event

Comment: Addition simple and official url: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs.clickcount?view=netframework-4.8